# FluentNHibernate auto-mapping collection of interface to multiple implementations

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an interface, `ISportsPerson`, which is implemented by some classes:

```
public interface ISportsPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Footballer : ISportsPerson
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Cricketer : ISportsPerson
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Salary { get; set; }
}

...
```

I have a class that has a collection of sports people

```
public class Award 
{
    public virtual IList<ISportsPerson> Winners { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously when I auto-map it, I get an error:

```
 NHibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: ISportsPerson
```

If I had only one implementation, I would map it in the override:

```
public class AwardOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Award>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Award> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany<Footballer>(x => x.Winners);
    }
}
```

As I have more than one, I'm not sure what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this modeled in the database?  Can you show us the schema for the relevant tables and columns?

Comment: It isn't yet - I'm doing this code first. I'm assuming one table for footballers, one for cricketers etc.

Comment: To get you started, you need to decide between using [inheritance](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance), or using [many-to-any](http://ayende.com/blog/3967/nhibernate-mapping-many-to-any).  I'll see if I can write something more detailed this weekend.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that a SportsPerson can win more than one award, right?  So at the very least that means using `HasManyToMany` instead of `HasMany`.

Comment: Actually, in this contrived case, which I tried to make more interesting than the reality of different types of report, `HasMany` suffices.